# UIButton strange behaviour

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have created a button

```
uploadBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    uploadBtn.frame = CGRectMake(35, 340, 250, 40);
    [uploadBtn setTitle:@"Upload" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [uploadBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(callUpload) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:uploadBtn];
```

for action

```
-(void)callUpload
{
    UploadViewController *uploadObj = [[UploadViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:uploadObj animated:YES];


}
```

but when i tap the button no event is firing up. Please help

Comment: Are you certain it's the button's fault? Have you placed a breakpoint in `callUpload` to see if it's being executed?

Comment: Are you sure your button is not outside the bounds of its superview? Touch events are not delivered to subviews which are outside of their superview's bounds, even if `clipToBounds=NO`.

Comment: i just added an alert to its action and it showed up. What could be the problem with navigation controller?

Comment: Either with the navigation controller, or `UploadViewController`.

Comment: Can you show us where UploadViewController gets initialized? Are you using a xib/storyboard or creating it's view manually? Also the UploadViewController.h might be useful.

Comment: I bet `self.navigationController` is `nil`

Comment: Either this, or his UploadViewController is not a view controller...

Answer (score 0):

Btn's method should have its sender included.

Update this line.

```
[uploadBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(callUpload:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And calling method with,

```
-(void)callUpload : (id) sender
{
    UploadViewController *uploadObj = [[UploadViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:uploadObj animated:YES];
}
```